# Substring of a Turkish String

Tags: javascript, string, utf-8, substring

I have a string like this

```
var element = "İstanbul";
```

and when I convert it to lower case like this:

```
var element = element.toLowerCase();
```

it becomes

```
"istanbul"
```

I need the substring of the lower case string `"istanbul`".

So, when I do this before the lowerCase operation

```
element.substr(0,2)
```

the output is correct

[image]

but when I do the following it's wrong from which I know `substr(0,2)` should give `"is"` instead of `i`

[image]

Why is it happening and how can I correct this?

Comment: Can you show some working code to debug.?

Comment: `str.substr(0,2)` is returning properly as per my knowledge. May be you need to refer [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp), it says `The substr() method extracts parts of a string, beginning at the character at the specified position, and returns the specified number of characters.`

Comment: yes, and the upper one is working correctly as per this information, but not the lower one.

Comment: Please add some code to debug. Where is the lower one you are trying and where the first one?

Comment: @titi23 I think all needed code for debugging is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because during changing to lower case the string is normalised, and the `İ` turns into 2 characters: `"i"` ( http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0069/index.htm) and `"̇"` (the latter is a diacritical mark http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm).

To prevent it you may split the string into characters using the ES2015 string iteration facilities and lower case the characters separately:

```
const arr_l_new = [...str].map(s => s.toLowerCase());
```

Then you can take the first N characters:

```
const first_2_chars = arr_l_new.slice(0, 2).join('');
```

Note: that if you count the length of the `first_2_chars` you will notice it has the length of `3`, due to the diacritic character, which is actually not visible for the lower case `i`.

```js
var str = "İstanbul";
const arr_l = [...str].map(s => s.toLowerCase());
const first_2_l = arr_l.slice(0, 2).join('');

console.log(first_2_l, first_2_l.length);
```

Comment: this I didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
element.toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp("İ".toLowerCase(), "g"), "i");
```

instead of

```
element.toLowerCase();
```